# Is it possible to get name property of a function without using new using ES6 in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like a general console.log snippet I can add to all functions without having to type out the function name each time.

```
function unknownName() {
 //psuedo code
 console.log(`this function's name: ${_thisFunction_.name}`); 
}
```

Restrictions:

1. arguments.callee.name doesn't work in strict mode.
2. I don't want to bind every function to be able to use 'this'
3. I don't know the function name in advance. Ex (from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)):

---

```
function doSomething() {}
doSomething.name; // "doSomething"
```

Comment: Are you just curious to know whether it’s possible or are you trying to solve a real problem where you need to know the function’s name?

Comment: Not generally possible. see last paragraph of [mdn on `arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee#A_use_of_arguments.callee_with_no_good_alternative)

Comment: @Xufox - I am trying to work out a general code snippet to add to all functions that could tie to a log manager, so a real problem.